# How to join the values of a dictionary if the keys match

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join

I have dictionary like this

```
Dic1 = 
{'SAP_10_L1': ['SAP_10_L1_R1_001.gz'],'SAP_10_L2': ['SAP_10_L2_R1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L1': ['SOS_4_5_L1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L2': ['SOS_4_5_L2.gz']}
```

Now I need to join the values of the Dic if the first part of the key is matching with first part of the value. The first part for the keys is until "L", the above example SAP_10 and SOA_4_5 are unique first parts. My aim is to have my `Dic1` looks like this :

```
Dic1 = {'SAP_10_L1': ['SAP_10_L1_R1_001.gz','SAP_10_L2_R1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L1': ['SOS_4_5_L1.gz','SOS_4_5_L2.gz']}
```

I tried this :

```
{i:list(j) for i in Dic1.keys() for j in Dic1.values()}
```

But it does not produce what I need. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might wanna be clear with "first part".

Comment: Where did the key `'SAP_10_L2'` go?

Comment: The first part is always until "L", the above example SAP_10, and SOA_4_5 first part

Comment: So after merging the values from key `SAP_10_L2', I do not want it so essentially I wanna create a new dictionary out of Dict1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

d = {'SAP_10_L1': ['SAP_10_L1_R1_001.gz'],'SAP_10_L2': ['SAP_10_L2_R1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L1': ['SOS_4_5_L1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L2': ['SOS_4_5_L2.gz']}

result = {}
for k,v in groupby(sorted(d.items()), lambda x: x[0].rsplit("_", 1)[0]):
    value = list(v)
    result[value[0][0]] = list(chain.from_iterable([i[1] for i in value]))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'SAP_10_L1': ['SAP_10_L1_R1_001.gz', 'SAP_10_L2_R1.gz'],
 'SOS-02289_4_5_L1': ['SOS_4_5_L1.gz', 'SOS_4_5_L2.gz']}
```